# Enable Controls QML ListView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

> The Problem

In a QML ListView delegate, there is a custom text field. This text field does not function when inside the list delegate, but works perfectly outside of said delegate.

> What I Already Know (Or think I know...)

I have already narrowed the problem down to focusing issues (Nothing in the list can brought into focus with a mouse or keyboard), and the same problem still applies to other Qt Quick Controls such as buttons and sliders.

> What I Need

I need to be able to use and interact with Qt Quick Controls such as buttons, text fields, etc. inside of list views and delegates. Thanks for your time and help!

> The Code

**List View**

```
ListView {

    id: root
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

    width: 800
    height: 900

    focus: true
    spacing: 15

    reuseItems: true
    maximumFlickVelocity: 2000
    verticalLayoutDirection: ListView.TopToBottom

    model: listModel
    delegate: listDelegate

    ListModel {

        id: listModel

        Component.onCompleted: {

            // Get document handler data object keys
            var keys = DocumentHandler.dataModelKeys

            // Create data object list elements
            for (const key of keys) {
                listModel.append(createElement(key))
            }
        }

        // Create list element
        function createElement(key) {

            // Return new list element
            return {

                key: key,
                type: DocumentHandler.getDataObjectType(key),
                documentPage: 1
            }
        }
    }

    Component {

        id: listDelegate

        Item {

            id: item
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            width: root.width
            height: 50

            Text {

                id: text
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                text: model.key
                font.bold: true
                font.pointSize: 18
            }

            CustomTextField {

                id: textField
                anchors.right: parent.right

                placeholderText: key
                widthScale: 1.75

                onAccepted: {

                    // Set new placeholder text
                    placeholderText = text

                    // Set new document handler data object value with key
                    DocumentHandler.setDataObjectValue(key, text)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        policy: ScrollBar.AsNeeded
    }

    MouseArea {

        anchors.fill: parent
        onWheel: (wheel)=> {

            // Scroll list view with wheel
            if (wheel.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier){
                if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0) {
                    mainTextEdit.font.pixelSize++
                } else {
                    mainTextEdit.font.pixelSize--
                }
                wheel.accepted = true
            } else {
                wheel.accepted = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Text Field**

```
TextField {

    id: root

    property var borderColor: "#3569be"
    property var backgroundColor: "#ffffff"

    property var textScale: 1.0
    property var widthScale: 1.0
    property var heightScale: 1.0

    color: "#000000"
    leftPadding: 7.5

    font.bold: true
    font.pointSize: 14 * root.textScale

    selectionColor: "#3569be"
    selectedTextColor: "#e0e0df"

    background: Rectangle {

        id: background
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        implicitWidth: 400 * root.widthScale
        implicitHeight: 45 * root.heightScale
        radius: 5

        color: root.backgroundColor

        border.width: 1.5
        border.color: root.borderColor
    }

    onEditingFinished: {

        // Remove from focus
        focus = false
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is with your MouseArea which sits on top of your Listview which captures all the mouse events.
So that you could not be able to get focus on your controls.

Please change the order or placing components(MouseArea then Listview).

Comment: @RamkumarR Thank you so much! Removing the mouse area worked like a charm! Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MouseArea captures all the mouse events since its z-order is higher than all other elements on the screen. Please change the z-order of the elements or Remove the MouseArea.